# Flexslider StartAt bug with sync

Tags: flexslider

I'm building a Flexslider which uses a thumbnail navigation. It's essentially identical to the Flexslider demo seen here http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html. It all works fine, but if I try to use the StartAt property it breaks the directional nav on the thumbnails. It jumps to the wrong place and sometimes kills the directionNav links.

This is my code. There are 5 #carousel items shown on the page at once, and one #slider item, the same as on the Flexslider demo.

```
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 230,
        itemMargin: 40,
        move: 5,
        startAt: 2,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
    });

    $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        startAt: 2,
        sync: "#carousel"
    });
```

If I run just the #carousel code which shows 5 items at once, I found that 'startAt' talks to one 'run of items' rather than one item. So startAt 0 will show items 1-5, startAt 1 will show items 6-10 and so on.

If there is just one item shown at a time (like on #slider) then the 'run' is 1 item. So startAt 0 is item 1, startAt 1 is item 2 and so on.

I think this is linked to the bug. When these are synced if I hit next on the directionNav of #carousel (when startAt of #carousel is 2), it jumps me to thumbnail items 16-20 (what would be run 3 if not synced). If I were to hit prev instead, it jumps me to items 6-10 (what would be run 1 if not synced).

Has anyone figured out a way around this bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i had this same issue, trying to do essentially the same thing.

I haven't found a solution but i have found the issue on github:

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/277

The issue seems to be that when flexslider is loading, the sync method is not available. So when loading, sync is not possible. I tried calling sync from the start event on the slider, with no luck. This is an issue that needs to be fixed in flexslider itself, which requires a patch.

I'm sorry i couldn't be more helpful, but i hope the work around in the github issue is helpful to you.